# Error with Composer Install - could not scan for classes inside a library dependency in /vendor directory

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php

I'm having issues getting composer to install and run laravel.

Currently on Windows, installed php(binary file or xampp) and composer(win installer or CLI). But facing the same issues when i try to do a composer install on a clean/fresh installation of composer

From https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation:

```
Via Laravel Installer
First, download the Laravel installer using Composer:

composer global require laravel/installer
```

When running this command, composer will create a composer.lock & composer.json file, but it will eventually face this error

```
Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor/symfony/polyfill-php73/Res
  ources/stubs" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

This is the stack trace

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:71
 Composer\Autoload\ClassMapGenerator::createMap() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:395
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->generateClassMap() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:381
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->addClassMapCode() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:277
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->dump() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:314
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:321
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:240
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:310
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:122
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/GlobalCommand.php:107
 Composer\Command\GlobalCommand->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:310
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:122
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:63
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:24
```

I'm trying to set up the development server for an existing laravel project, and when i git clone the source code and do a composer install, i will face this exact same problem.

I've scoured the internet solutions, but none of them worked for me so far.

Things i've tried:

- Remove cache, Remove vendor directory and install again --> same error
- Permissions issue --> Don't think this is a case, user is admin
- Reinstall & Reformatted my computer twice  --> same problem

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is the version of composer?

Comment: Composer version is 2.0.5, php version is 7.4.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that some file is corrupted. To solved, you should delete `vendor` folder and run `composer install`.

Update:

You should downgrade version of composer, you should use `composer self-update 2.0.4`

Comment: Thanks. But i can verify that this method does not work for me. Deleting cache && /vendor directory, then composer install/update will not resolve this error. Tried this many times. I actually face this error even on a clean installation (e.g. %appdata%/composer/vendor does not exist) and composer install still fails with the same error.

Comment: Did you try to downgrade version of composer using `composer self-update 2.0.4`? I think this issue is related to version of composer.

Comment: Yes you are right. downgrading from 2.0.5 to 2.0.4 actually works. Thank you!